# Obtaining inner class variable from deserialized json using gson

Tags: java, json, oop, deserialization, gson

I'm trying to access variables from an inner class of a deserialized json object. Below is the code I've used.

```
package jsonparser;

public class JsonParser {

private long uid = 0;
private String username, secret, filter, machine_id, access_token,
        session_key = null;


    public JsonParser() {

     }

     public static class Profile {
        private String last_name, first_name, pic_square, name = null;
        private long uid = 0;
        final JsonParser outer = JsonParser.this;

         public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
         }

         public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
            this.last_name = last_name;
         }

         public String getFirst_name() {
         return first_name;
         }

         public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
          this.first_name = first_name;
         }

             public String getPic_square() {
           return pic_square;
         }

         public void setPic_square(String pic_square) {
          this.pic_square = pic_square;
         }

         public String getName() {
         return name;
         }

         public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
         }

         public long getUid() {
        return uid;
         }

         public void setUid(long uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
         }

         public Profile() {
         }
       }
}
```

And in another class:

```
JsonParser jp = gson.fromJson(Data, JsonParser.class);
```

where Data looks like:

```
{
    "uid": 123,
    "username": "Hello",
    "secret": "87920",
    "filter": "nf",
    "machine_id": "machine_id",
    "access_token": "access_token",
    "session_key": "123e",
    "profile": {
        "last_name": "Tan",
        "uid": 123,
        "first_name": "Sally",
        "pic_square": "url.jpg",
        "name": "Sally Tan"
    }
}
```

How would I be able to access the last_name in the profile inner class from the jp object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field

```
private Profile profile;

public Profile getProfile() { return profile; }
```

to the outer class `JsonParser`. Then you can use

```
jp.getProfile().getLast_name();
```

Note: The name `JsonParser` is confusing since it doesn't parse anything - it stores the parse *results*. Rename it to `Config` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First remove

```
final JsonParser outer = JsonParser.this;
```

from your code. This is an illegal construct because `this` cannot be referenced from a static context.

Then add

```
private Profile profile;
```

to your JsonParser class right below the definition of the other members like username, secret,...

With this member in place the GSon Parser will fill it on your call to `gson.fromJson(...)`.

You can add a getter Method to access your sub-structure from outside.